# Images, Buttons nor ToggleButtons don't display on any laptop

Tags: wpf, xaml

In this particular case, images are bound to **Buttons** and **ToggleButtons**, which are inside of **ToolBars**, and ToolBars are underneath a **ToolBarTray**.

For some reason, any image or button that is put anywhere on the **MainWindow** doesn't appear  when running the app on a laptop.

I tried adding an image outside the ToolBars and the ToolBarTray, so I know if the problem is somehow connected with these two controls, but it's probably not. The image wouldn't show up anyway.

When I try to debug the app on my computer or another computer, everything works just fine.

When I run the app on a **computer**

[image]

When I run the app on a **laptop**

[image]

‎‎**XAML:**

```
<ToolBarTray x:Name="homeTray" Margin="0,28,0,863" Background="#FFEEF5FD" ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True">
    <ToolBar Band="0" BandIndex="0">
        <Button x:Name="cut" ToolTip="Cut (CTRL + X)" Click="Cut">
            <Image Source="./Resources/Text-Formatting/cut.png" Height="25" Width="25"/>
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>
    <ToolBar Band="2" BandIndex="0">
        <Button x:Name="copy" ToolTip="Copy (CTRL + C)" Click="Copy">
            <Image Source="./Resources/Text-Formatting/copy.png" Height="25" Width="25"></Image>
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>
    <ToolBar Band="0" Margin="63,10,-63,-10">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbFonts" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Background="#FFFBFBFB" BorderBrush="#FFB4B1B1" SelectionChanged="TxtFont" TextInput="ChangeFontByIntellisense"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbFontSize" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEditable="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" BorderBrush="#FFB4B1B1" Margin="15, 0, 0, 1" Background="White" SelectionChanged="TxtFontSize"/>
    </ToolBar>

    <ToolBar Band="0" Margin="85,47,-223,-55">
        <Button>
            <Image x:Name="alignmentLeft" ToolTip="Align left (CTRL + L)" Source="./Resources/Alignment/align-left.png" MouseDown="Alignment"></Image>
        </Button>

        <Button>
            <Image x:Name="alignmentCenter" ToolTip="Align center (CTRL + E)" Source="./Resources/Alignment/align-center.png" MouseDown="Alignment"></Image>
        </Button>

        <Button>
            <Image x:Name="alignmentRight" ToolTip="Align right (CTRL + R)" Source="./Resources/Alignment/align-right.png" MouseDown="Alignment"></Image>
        </Button>

        <Button>
            <Image x:Name="alignmentJustify" ToolTip="Justify (CTRL + J)" Source="./Resources/Alignment/align-justify.png" MouseDown="Alignment"></Image>
        </Button>

    </ToolBar>

    <ToolBar Margin="-172,77,149,-66" ToolTip="Letters height">
        <Button Margin="0,2,0,1">
            <Image Height="24" Width="24" x:Name="txtHeight" Source="./Resources/Text-Formatting/Aa.png" MouseLeftButtonDown="AaMenuOpen">
                <Image.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="ALL CAPITAL" FontSize="17" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Click="AaOptions"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="all small" FontSize="17" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Click="AaOptions"></MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="First letter capital" FontSize="17" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Click="AaOptions"></MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Image.ContextMenu>
            </Image>
        </Button>
    </ToolBar>

    <ToolBar Band="2" Margin="60,-8,28,8">
        <ToggleButton Command="EditingCommands.ToggleBold" x:Name="bold" ToolTip="Bold (CTRL + B)">
            <Image Source="./Resources/Text-Formatting/bold.png" Height="12.5" Width="12.5"/>
        </ToggleButton>
    </ToolBar>
    <ToolBar Band="2" Margin="-28,-8,34,8">
        <ToggleButton Command="EditingCommands.ToggleItalic" x:Name="italic" ToolTip="Italic (CTRL + I)">
            <Image Source="./Resources/Text-Formatting/italic.png" Height="15" Width="15"></Image>
        </ToggleButton>
    </ToolBar>
    <ToolBar Band="2" Margin="-36,-8,42,8">
        <ToggleButton Command="EditingCommands.ToggleUnderline" x:Name="underline" ToolTip="Underlined (CTRL + U)">
            <Image Source="./Resources/Text-Formatting/underline.png" Height="18" Width="18"></Image>
        </ToggleButton>
    </ToolBar>

    <ToolBar Band="2" Margin="-99,33,177,-27">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnReadOnly" ToolTip="Read-only" Click="TxtReadOnly">
            <Image x:Name="readOnly" Source="Resources/Text-Formatting/readonly.png" Height="21" Width="21"/>
        </ToggleButton>
    </ToolBar>

    <ToolBar Margin="-47,44,-26,-42" RenderTransformOrigin="3.719,0.568" ToolTip="Foreground color">
        <toolkit:ColorPicker x:Name="foregroundColor" Width="40" Margin="10" SelectedColorChanged="ForegroundColor"/>
    </ToolBar>

    <ToolBar Margin="-51,76,-22,-74" RenderTransformOrigin="3.719,0.568" ToolTip="Background color">
        <toolkit:ColorPicker x:Name="backgroundColor" Width="40" Margin="10" SelectedColorChanged="BackgroundColor"/>
    </ToolBar>

    <ToolBar Band="2" Margin="-166,-5,240,11">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="superscript" ToolTip="Superscript" Click="Superscript">
            <Image Source="Resources/Text-Formatting/superscript.png" Height="21" Width="21"/>
        </ToggleButton>
    </ToolBar>

    <ToolBar Band="2" Margin="-284,33,365,-27">
        <ToggleButton x:Name="subscript" ToolTip="Subscript" Click="Subscript">
            <Image Source="Resources/Text-Formatting/subscript.png" Height="21" Width="21"/>
        </ToggleButton>
    </ToolBar>

</ToolBarTray>
```

Labels shown in the pictures above:

```
<Label x:Name="lbCut" Content="Cut" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
<Label x:Name="lbCopy" Content="Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="56,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="rectSeparator" Fill="#FFC1C1F9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="110" Margin="99,33,0,0" Stroke="#FFC1C1F9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1"/>
<Label Content="Alignment" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="388,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Comment: Not sure this is your only problem but you have large fixed margins. Never use large margins to position controls. Use panels to arrange content instead. Your layout will break when you deliver it to a machine with different display sizes. Like say a laptop.

Comment: DockPanel, ToolBarPanel, or StackPanel?

Comment: Depends exactly what you want to do. Putting them all in one toolbartray would be the simplest scenario. I suggest you start just by removing the margins completely.

Answer (score 0):

I put everything in one ToolBarTray and it solved the problem.

Thank you, Andy, for giving me the advice.